# Как анимировать SVG фильтр FeComponentTransfer?

Tags: javascript, css3, html5, svg, svg-animation

Кто-нибудь знает, как использовать тег `animate в feFuncRGB` в `feComponentTransfer`?
 У меня есть фильтр SVG, и мне нужно показать / скрыть его по щелчку с `transition`.

Что-то вроде этого:

```js
$('img').click( function() {
  $("#animate").beginElement();
});
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg-filters">
    <filter id="duotone">
        <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone_cyan_blue">
            <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.2489 0.9589">
                <animate 
                id="animate"
                attributeName="tableValues" 
                dur="2s" 
                from="0 1" 
                to="0.2489 0.9589" 
                fill="freeze" 
                />
            </feFuncR>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
</svg>
```

И сделать тоже самое для каналов `feFuncG` и `feFuncB`.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/55689244/7394871

Comment: Если интересно могу привести пример как сделать подобное на канве при помощи прямых манипуляций с пикселями, как делать тожесамое на webgl есть в соседнем топике про radial blur

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Конечно интересно, делай

Answer (score 5):

Одним из решений будет использование изображения SVG c применением фильтра `feComponentTransfer` с красным каналом `feFuncR`. Например, так:

**Анимация применение фильтра начнётся после клика на изображении**

```js
svg.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  _animate.beginElement();
})
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" width="300" height="300" >
    <filter id="duotone">
        <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone_red">
            <feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0 1">
               <animate 
                id="_animate"
                attributeName="tableValues" 
                dur="4s" 
                values="0 1;1 0;1 0;0 1" 
                fill="freeze"
                begin="svg.mouseover"
                />
            </feFuncR>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  
  <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" width="300" height="300" filter="url(#duotone)"></image>
</svg>
```

Анимация зелёного канала `feFuncG`:

```js
svg.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  _animate.beginElement();
})
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" width="300" height="300" >
    <filter id="duotone">
        <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone_green">
            <feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0 1">
               <animate 
                id="_animate"
                attributeName="tableValues" 
                dur="3s" 
                values="0 1;1 0;1 0;0 1" 
                fill="freeze"
                begin="svg.mouseover"
                />
            </feFuncG>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  
  <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" width="300" height="300" filter="url(#duotone)"></image>
</svg>
```

Анимация синего канала `feFuncВ`:

```js
svg.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  _animate.beginElement();
})
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" width="300" height="300" >
    <filter id="duotone">
        <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone_blue">
            <feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0 1">
               <animate 
                id="_animate"
                attributeName="tableValues" 
                 dur="3s" 
                values="0 1;1 0;1 0;0 1" 
                fill="freeze"
                begin="svg.mouseover"
                />
            </feFuncB>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  
  <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" width="300" height="300" filter="url(#duotone)"></image>
</svg>
```

Анимация альфа канала (прозрачности):

```js
svg.addEventListener("click",() =>{
  _animate.beginElement();
})
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" width="300" height="300" >
    <filter id="duotone">
        <feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" result="duotone_A">
            <feFuncA type="table" tableValues="0 2">
               <animate 
                id="_animate"
                attributeName="tableValues" 
                dur="2s" 
                values="0 1;1 0.1" 
                fill="freeze"
                begin="svg.click"
                />
            </feFuncA>
        </feComponentTransfer>
    </filter>
  
  <image xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/darwin300.jpg" width="300" height="300" filter="url(#duotone)"></image>
</svg>
```

Примечание переводчика:

> `feComponentTransfer` один из самых мощных примитивов фильтра SVG. Он
>   дает нам контроль над отдельными каналами RGBA нашего источника
>   графики, позволяя создавать в SVG эффекты, подобные Photoshop.
>   Более подробно [здесь](https://habr.com/ru/post/439874/)

В следующем примере для красного канала будет применён набор атрибутов `type="linear"` `slope="1"` `intercept="0"`.

При наведении курсора будет анимирован атрибут `slope` `values="1;4"`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И лето плавно заменится осенью.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="svg" width="400" height="300" >
    <filter id="duotone">
  <fecomponenttransfer>
  <fefuncR type="linear" slope="1" intercept="0" >
   <animate 
                id="_animate"
                attributeName="slope" 
                dur="3s" 
                values="1;4;4;1" 
                fill="freeze"
                begin="svg.mouseover"
                /> 
  <fefuncG type="linear" slope="1" intercept="0" />
  <fefuncB type="linear" slope="1" intercept="0" />
</fecomponenttransfer>
    </filter>
  
  <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PwDWY.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" filter="url(#duotone)"></image>
</svg>
```